# Find the binary version number of an R package from a repository

Tags: r

If I use `old.packages()` this will give me a dataframe with, among other things, the actual version of a package in the repository. This is, however, the version of the package that has to be compiled. Is there a neat way to get the information on the binary version?

Background: I would like to compare the version of my installed packages and comparte them to the latest build of the binary version of the package. As I understood (and is also my experience) it is less error-prone to install binary packages on a Windows machine.

Comment: Do you just want `old.packages(type="binary")`? I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do. Can you provide some sort of specific example that we can use for testing?

Comment: d'oh! my solution may be reinventing the wheel ...

Comment: Thanks for both inputs. The "type = binary" does the trick.

Comment: If your problem is solved you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept the answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you a list of the Windows binaries that are available for a particular repository for a particular major version of R:

```r
repo <- "http://cran.r-project.org"
r_major <- gsub("\\.[0-9]*$", "", as.character(getRversion()))
url <- sprintf("%s/bin/windows/contrib/%s", repo, r_major)
rr <- readLines(url)
pkglines <- grep("\\.zip", rr, value = TRUE)
pkgs <- gsub("^.*>([[:alpha:]0-9.]*_[0-9.-]+\\.zip)<.*$", "\\1", pkglines)
```

```r
head(pkgs)
[1] "A3_1.0.0.zip"          "AATtools_0.0.2.zip"    "ABACUS_1.0.0.zip"     
[4] "ABC.RAP_0.9.0.zip"     "ABCanalysis_1.2.1.zip" "ABCoptim_0.15.0.zip"
```

From here you can use `strsplit`/`gsub` etc. to drop the `.zip` extension and separate the package names and version numbers ...

As @MrFlick suggests, `old.packages(type="binary")` may already do what you want.

(It would actually be better/easier to read `https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES` and go from there -- easier than trying to pick apart HTML ...)